# c# marshaling IDispatch pointer

Tags: c#, com, idispatch

In an Unmanaged IDispatch interface my code calls, one of the functions is

```
    [id(1), helpstring("method")]
    HRESULT Test(IDispatch* pDispatch, [out, retval] long* pRC);
```

To call this I'm trying:

```
        Object myObj =  Activator.CreateInstance(
                        Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyObject.ProgID"));
        Object [] args = new Object[1];
        args[0] = myObj
        Object result = So.GetType().InvokeMember("Test", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, So,args);
```

Clearly this doesn't work. Does anyone have any advice on how to marshal my object as an IDispatch pointer?

Thanks